# jquery dynamic data not getting displayed

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, sublimetext2

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
        function swapContent(cv)
        {
            $_("#myDiv").html("Put animated .gif here").show();
            var url= "myphpscript.php";
            $_post(url,{contentVar:cv},function(data){
                $_("#myDiv").html(data).show();
            });
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a href = "#" onClick = "return false" onmousedown = "javascript.swapContent('Con1')"> Content1 </a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
    <a href = "#" onClick = "return false" onmousedown = "javascript.swapContent('Con2')"> Content2 </a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
    <a href = "#" onClick = "return false" onmousedown = "javascript.swapContent('Con3')"> Content3 </a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
    <div id = "myDiv"> My Default Content 1</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**myphpscript.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $_contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
    if($_contentVar == 'Con1')
    {
        echo ' My Defaut Content';
    }
else if($contentVar == 'Con2')
    {
        echo ' My Defaut Content 2';
    }
else if($contentVar == 'Con3')
    {
        echo ' My Defaut Content 3';
    }
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to display some dynamic content when the `onmousedown` event is done. I haven't done the animation yet, but just I wanted to get the required `divs` to be changed on choosing the different links but some how it doesn't seem to work.The **jQuery** file has been correctly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

COndition wrong

```
$_contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];


if( $_contentVar == 'Con1')  //here you are using   $contentVa not  $_contentVar
```

Comment: check whats coming in  $_contentVar from server and put console logs and try

Comment: use  $("#myDiv").html("Put animated .gif here").show(); in function not $_("#myDiv")

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: javascript is not defined .This is my error

Comment: is the content in the <a> </a> tag correct because it shows an error in those line only

Comment: Try onmousedown = "swapContent('Con1')" instead of onmousedown = "javascript.swapContent('Con1')"

Comment: Problem I see is with how you call the function it should be javascript:swapContent('Con1') and not javascript.swapContent('Con1'). You have put '.' instead of ':'. Check my post

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have used _ in `$_("#myDiv")..` I think your javascript code should be

```
    function swapContent(cv)
    {
        $("#myDiv").html("Put animated .gif here").show();
        var url= "myphpscript.php";
        $.post(url,{contentVar:cv},function(data){
            $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
        });
    }
```

and also another problem I see is with how you call the function it should be javascript:swapContent('Con1') not javascript.swapContent('Con1'). You have put '.' instead of ':'

so the links should be

```
<a href = "#" onClick = "return false" onmousedown = "javascript:swapContent('Con1')"> Content1 </a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
<a href = "#" onClick = "return false" onmousedown = "javascript:swapContent('Con2')"> Content2 </a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
<a href = "#" onClick = "return false" onmousedown = "javascript:swapContent('Con3')"> Content3 </a> &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;
```

You should also change the variable name in PHP script, which I hope you already knew